Suggestion: Merge nxtcoin into nxt
nxtcoin and nxt discuss the same thing. nxt has slightly more questions, and already has a tag wiki; we should keep that one, and merge nxtcoin into it.

Good catch, I merged nxtcoin into nxt.
